# Re-rendering in React functional component - why this behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-props, react-functional-component

This question concerns the definition of callback functions inside functional components, with the callback functions being passed down as props to child functional components.
I am aware that when defining functions inside functional components and those functions are being passed on as props to child components we should use *useCallback*. In this example I am deliberately not using it.

I have a dummy React app as below:

**App.jsx**

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent';
import TestComponent2 from './components/TestComponent2';

function App() {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    console.log('Defining myArrowfunc');
    const myArrowFunc = () => console.log('Hello!');
    console.log('myArrowfunc defined');

    return (
        <>
            <TestComponent message={message} myArrowFunc={myArrowFunc} />
            <TestComponent2 myArrowFunc={myArrowFunc} />
            <input
                type="text"
                value={message}
                onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                    console.log('Setting message');
                    setMessage("x");
            }}>Set to x</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**TestComponent.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function TestComponent(props) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`TestComponent.useEffect, props.message = ${props.message}`);
    }, [props]);
    
    return <h2>TestComponent - {props.message}</h2>;
}

export default TestComponent;
```

**TestComponent2.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function TestComponent2(props) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`TestComponent2.useEffect`);
    }, [props.myArrowFunc]);
    
    return <h2>TestComponent2 - Placeholder</h2>;
}

export default TestComponent2;
```

Starting the app, the page loads and we are here:

[image: Initial app load]

In the console window everything looks like expected. The *console.log* statements *Defining myArrowFunc* and *myArrowFunc defined* ran, and we can see the *console.log* statements from the *useEffect* hook within *TestComponent* and *TestComponent2* which ran after they were rendered.

Now we click on the button *Set to x*, which invokes the callback function attached to the *onClick* event of the button. This callback calls `setMessage("x")` which updates the state of the *App* component and consequently triggers a re-render of the component.

In the console window we can see that the *App* functional component ran (e.g. from the `console.log("Defining myArrowFunc)`) and one can also see that the *useEffect* hooks of the child components ran after they were re-rendered.

[image]

Now, that *TestComponent* re-rendered is of course understandable. *message* state is a prop on *TestComponent* which would cause a re-render of *TestComponent*. Also, in the dependency array of *TestComponent* is specified `props` (not `props.message`), but `props` is a new object on every render (right?) and hence the reference comparison tells us `props` has changed and so *useEffect* runs.

That the *useEffect* hook of *TestComponent2* ran can be understood (right?) from the fact that *myArrowFunc* is re-defined on each render of *App*, and so the prop passed to *TestComponent2* has in fact changed (reference comparison).

Here comes the part where I become confused: the *message* state in *App* now holds "x", and so additional clicks to the button will not change the state, and so should not trigger a re-render of *App* (and any child components dependant). When I click the button the following output happens:

[image]

The statements `console.log('Defining myArrowfunc');` and `console.log('myArrowfunc defined');` ran. What does this mean? Did the component re-render? If the *App* function ran, then it should have defined a new *myArrowFunc* (right?), and since *TestComponent2* takes that as a prop, it should have re-rendered and run its *useEffect* hook?

What's interesting as well is that when I again click the button, it does **not** look like *App* ran, the output becomes only "Setting message".

Would very much appreciate an outline / explanation of what exactly is going on here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you click the button, a console log with setting message will run, and then a setState with will make a re-render.

At the following click, react is clever enough to see that the state you are setting is the same as before so it doesn't re-render

If you change then, the value and click the button, it will re-render, but not for the following cases with the same value.

To sum up, the first's console.log won't run if there's not a re-render, and the procedure of react--if default--memoizing will prevent it

Comment: But why do I see the outputs from ```console.log('Defining myArrowfunc')```and ```console.log('myArrowfunc defined');``` after the second click?

Comment: Strange, but I think it could be a passed same value in case of an induced error or some stadistic strategy. Anyways it looks strange to me

Comment: React may re-render some part of your app for various internal reasons. I'm guessing it renders the top level component for one of these reasons, then its realizes no state has changed and therefore decides that the child component wouldn't be any different, so it skips rendering them. I wouldn't worry about it if I were you. React is declarative, you tell it what you want things to look like and then let it do the magic. You aren't meant to be managing rendering this closely.

Comment: @AlexWayne I see, that makes sense. But wouldn't ```myArrowFunc``` be a new object (function really) after the second click and hence an "updated prop" from the perspective of ```TestComponent2``` for example?

Comment: If state hasn't been changed, then any props shouldn't be different. In a react app the same state should always produce the same result. Other rules like checking the identity of props to see if a re-render of child components is required would be secondary to that.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thank you, that clears it up for me (I think). Essentially React is saying "Yes, the identity of ```myArrowFunc``` is different, but nothing has changed in the parent so I will not re-render the child component anyway"?

Comment: I believe that's right. In fact the one additional render of the parent may even be due to the fact that React is looking for a `useEffect` that might then update state. When it finds no change to state in the parent component, it knows it's safe to skip that render the next time, too. React is full of performance optimizations like this that you shouldn't have to care much about.